# Mini Makefile always rebuild using compass

Tags: makefile, sass

I have this small Makefile here

```
SHELL  = /bin/sh                                                                   

.PHONY: clean all                                                                  

all: ../../htdocs/css                                                              

../../htdocs/css: ../sass                                                          
    cd ../../ && compass compile -e `cat .env | cut -d " " -f 1`                   

clean:                                                                             
    rm -f ../../htdocs/css/*
```

It does always rebuild. The directory '../../htdocs/css' does exist. Any ideas?

Comment: Ask yourself: is make able to figure whether the target is out-of-date?

Comment: More specifically from devnull's comment: when does the time last modified for `../../htdocs/css` change?  When does the time last modified for `../sass` change?  Why is the latter always more recent than the former?  The answers to these questions will show you why make is always running that rule.

Comment: Thank you guys, I have not much experience with Makefiles. I added touch htdocs/css and it works.